# Can somone explain facebook starspace?

Tags: graph, neural-networks

I have googled enough for days but i cant find a clear intuitive document about this embedding technique. 
In their paper they say : We present StarSpace, a general-purpose neural embedding model that can solve a wide variety of problems.
But they don't explain how. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You run it against a bunch of documents, presumably facebook posts and it maps them similarly to the image below

This enables it to make judgements about how similar two posts are and thus make recommendations to users about what they might find interesting, presumably adverts

[image]